# Angular 5 Hide nav element if user is logged in

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication

I've implemented a bootstrap navbar in my Angular app with a couple of links. I want to hide the `login` and `register` links if the user is logged in, and show the `profile` link. If the user is not logged in, show `login` and `register`, hide `profile`.

```
...
<li class="nav-item" *ngIf="user">
 <a class="nav-link" href="profile" id="profile" >Profile</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item" *ngIf="!user">
 <a class="nav-link" href="login"><button class="btn btn-sm" >Login</button></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item" *ngIf="!iuser">
 <a class="nav-link" href="register"><button class="btn btn-sm" >Register</button></a>
</li>
...
```

I'm using firebase for authentication and checking if the user is logged in like this:

```
checkUser() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        console.log('logged in', user);
      } else {
        console.log('not logged in');
      }
    });
  }
```

The function works just fine but it seems the `*ngIf` in the navbar doesn't pick up the `user` from the function.

Comment: Define a `user` variable in your class and set its value in the callback: `public user: string; ... firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => { this.user = user; })`.

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot set property 'user' of undefined`

Comment: Make sure that you define the callback as `(user) => { ... }`, not as `function (user) { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks. This works but the changes are lost when I refresh the page.

Comment: When you refresh the page in the browser (e.g. with the F5 key), the application is restarted. You can use `localStorage` to save the state of your application between runs.

Comment: Thanks. How do I accept your answer?

Comment: You are welcome. :-) You can post the correct code as an answer and accept it (to indicate that the solution was found).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to reference nav links is to use [routerLink](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-links).

```
...
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/profile" routerLinkActive="active" 
    *ngIf="user">Profile</a>
</li>
...
```

Define a user variable in your class and set its value in the callback: `public user: string;`

...

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
     if (user) {
     this.user = user;
     console.log('logged in', user);
   } else {
     console.log('not logged in');
   }
 });
```

Thanks to [ConnorsFan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1009922/connorsfan) for the insight.

Answer (score 3):

You can create new subject and emit a value and use in ngIf with the help of async pipe should work. Please try as follows,

```
...
isUserLoggerdIn$ = new Subject<any>();

checkUser() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanges((user) => {
    if(user) {
      this.isUserLoggedIn$.next(true);
    } else {
      this.isUserLoggedIn$.next(false);
    }
  });
}
...
```

Then in your template you can achieve as follows

```
...
<li class="nav-item" *ngIf="isUserLoggerdIn$ | async">
 <a class="nav-link" href="profile" id="profile" >Profile</a>
</li>
...
```

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined`. Also, you have `isUserLoggerdIn$` in your declaration and `isUserLoggedIn$` inside the function. Is that a typo?

Comment: Please convert the callback function as arrow function and try i will edit the code as such... because context varies inside that function